# Can I evaluate a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have to Pad a string and return it before I can do a Substring on the string.
Is there a way I can evaluate the string after the padding and combine the two statements into 1 line?

This works

```
    string numberOfRecords = allRecords.Count().ToString().PadLeft(8, '0');
    numberOfRecords = numberOfRecords.Substring(numberOfRecords.Length-8,8);
```

But this does not

```
    string numberOfRecords = allRecords.Count().ToString();
    numberOfRecords = numberOfRecords.PadLeft(8, '0').Substring(numberOfRecords.Length-8,8);
```

Comment: Why would you want to call  `Substring` after the `PadLeft` call? Isn't the `Substring` essentially a no-op in that scenario?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking, nor what you're trying to do. Based on the little bit of information here, it seems likely that you should simply format the `allRecords.Count()` value with a custom numeric format that specifies eight digits and leave the `PadLeft()` and `Substring()` out of it. Beyond that, what _specific_ problem are you actually having that we can help you with?

Comment: @petelids Unless the number was larger than 99,999,999. In which case, the result would be off by orders of magnitude (100,000,000 would be truncated to 10,000,000)

Comment: You're quite right @Rob, I was thinking of smaller numbers that required padding. At a guess, using substring on larger numbers would be even worse but it's hard to tell what the OP wants to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

`string` is immutable in C#. In the first case, you are doing `PadLeft(8, '0')` and assigning to `numberOfRecords`. So it contains updated value (with `PadLeft`).

But in the second case, you are doing `PadLeft` but the value of `numberOfRecords` will be same. This will fail when you do `numberOfRecords.Length` which will be original value (`allRecords.Count().ToString()`) and may throw an exception.